# Using JS & JSON and simple html form to Update price

Tags: javascript, html, json, shopify

I am trying to use create setup where you input a postcode, submit a form and then using JavaScript check if the first 4 characters of the postcode match one in some JSON data and if it does change the price on the page. This will be for a Shopify website so any assistance on how to implement it on there would be great.

At the moment the page refreshes when I submit the form and nothing happens.

Here's what I have so far it's quite early stages still:

```js
async function checkZones() {
  // const requestURL = "{{ 'zones.json' | asset_url }}";
  // const request = new Request(requestURL);
  //const response = await fetch(request);
  // const zones = await response.json();
  const zones = [{
      "name": "zone 1",
      "postcodes": [
        "test1",
        "test2",
        "test3",
        "test4",
        "test5",
        "test6",
        "test7",
        "test8",
        "test9",
        "test10"
      ],
      "cost": 10.8
    },
    {
      "name": "zone 2",
      "postcodes": [
        "test12",
        "test13",
        "test14",
        "test15",
        "test16",
        "test17",
        "test18",
        "test19",
        "test18",
        "test19",
        "test20"
      ],
      "cost": 16.8
    }
  ]
  console.log(zones);
  updatePrice()
}

function updatePrice(zone) {
  const postcodeFormInput = document.querySelector('#postcodeForm input[type="text]"');

  const postcodes = zone.postcodes;
  for (const code of postcodes) {
    if (postcodeFormInput.value.contains(code)) {
      const productPrice = document.querySelector('#ProductPrice-product-template').textContent;
      if (code === "test1") {
        const newPrice = productPrice + zone.cost;
        document.querySelector('#ProductPrice-product-template').innerHTML = newPrice;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="checkZones()" id="postcodeForm">
  <input type="text">
  <button type="submit">Update Costs</button>
</form><span id="ProductPrice-product-template">0.00</span>
```

Comment: So, what's your problem? What's not working?

Comment: @technophyle It's the updatePrice function, not sure why it's not working I'm afraid.

Comment: I made you a [mcve] - you need to prevent the submission

Answer (score 1):

There were quite a few issues here

Some of them

1. Use the submit event handler and prevent the submission
2. You were not passing the zones to the function that needed them
3. You need to make sure the amounts you use in the calculation are numeric and not strings (which you get from innerText and .value) - I use the unary plus `+` to convert to number or 0 if undefined and the conditional chaining operator `?.` to handle a missing postcode
4. You can use find to get the zone that has the array that includes the postcode

```js
const checkZones = () => {
  // here is a simpler fetch
  //fetch("{{ 'zones.json' | asset_url }}")
  // .then(response => response.json())
  // .then(zones => updatePrice(zones));
  updatePrice(zones)
}
const postcodeFormInput = document.querySelector("#postcodeForm input[type=text]");
const productTemplate = document.getElementById('ProductPrice-product-template');
const updatePrice = (zones) => {

  const postCode = postcodeFormInput.value;
  console.log("Input",postCode)
  const cost = +zones.find(({postcodes}) => postcodes.includes(postCode))?.cost; // 0 if not found
  
  if (!cost) return; // not found
  const productPrice = +productTemplate.textContent;
  const newPrice = productPrice + cost;
  productTemplate.innerHTML = newPrice;
};

document.getElementById("postcodeForm").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
  checkZones()
})
```

```html
<form id="postcodeForm">
  <input type="text">
  <button type="submit">Update Costs</button>
</form>
<span id="ProductPrice-product-template">0.00</span>







<script>
// testdata to be deleted when you uncomment the fetch
const zones = [{ "name": "zone 1", "postcodes": [ "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7", "test8", "test9", "test10" ], "cost": 10.8 }, { "name": "zone 2", "postcodes": [ "test12", "test13", "test14", "test15", "test16", "test17", "test18", "test19", "test18", "test19", "test20" ], "cost": 16.8 } ];
</script>
```